# Casting model to another model that extend the original

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to cast a model to another one that extends the same model.
Is there a build in way in Laravel this achieve this?

**Example**
In the code below I would like to cast `User` to `ExtendedUser`

```
class User extends Model
{
...
}
```

```
class ExtendedUser extends User
{
...
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve by extending the model class?

Comment: This might help you: https://gist.github.com/borzilleri/960035

Comment: I trying to access some logic that's only available in the `ExtendedUser` Model that was added using a trait. And I'm not able to edit the original User model since it's located in an external library